# Azure IoT Edge Batching behaviour

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-edge

I am noticing the following behavior using IoT Edge batching: I know that my individual message size is less than 200 bytes. I can batch these comfortably 1000 at a time and send them to IoT Hub when I am not using IoT Edge. When using IoT Edge, the maximum batch that is being sent to IoT Hub is 100 messages. I can set the environment variable "MaxUpstreamBatchSize" on EdgeHub to a value below 100 and the batch size would change accordingly, but anything above 100 is ignored and the batch size defaults to 100. When I don't enter a value for the "MaxUpstreamBatchSize" I get batch size of 10. So is 100 the maximum batch size that we can get from IoT Edge?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did a quick search on iotedge source code and noticed [AsyncEndpointExecutor.cs](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/master/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Routing.Core/endpoints/AsyncEndpointExecutor.cs) stating: "This block emits a batch when the batch size is reached or the **batch timer times out.**"

Therefore I believe you are being hit by that time-out and therefore your batches are smaller than defined on environment variable "MaxUpstreamBatchSize".

You can debug your code and double check if that's what is happening. Then open a new issue under iot edge repo for a feature request if you want to have an environment variable to disable the timer or make it larger.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have looked at the detailed logs of the edgeHub but there is nothing to indicate the issue with batch timer. Any ideas how to debug this issue? And how can I find the value of the batch timer?

Comment: I believe the only way to debug this is to build the source code and follow the [devguide](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/master/doc/devguide.md).

Comment: @BMajeed still blocked? If not please mark this as answer or share your solution. Thanks!